# How to change a packet data with scapy?

Tags: scapy

How can one change a packet data with scapy?

I tried to use `sniff()` and then `send()` the edited packet, but it won't work as the original packet has already reached it's destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"but it won't work as the original packet has already reached it's destination."

So first you need to setup some MiTM solution so all the communications between both ends
traverse though your device, and let you modifiy packet data.

Some wll known software pacakages for this functionality /attack are ettercap and cain/abel.

Comment: Or more simply: an old-school "hub" (not switch). As long as the traffic is not encrypted, another host on the hub could sniff it out. Or you can route the traffic through a dedicated sniffer host ("connection sharing")

Answer (score 4):

iTayb,

Seems you are interested in proxying some sort of service using scapy? If so which one?

First order of business is some how have the packets pass through the box running scapy. Do this by setting the gateway on the remote machine to match the scapy box. If this is for some sort of pentesting you will need to spoof some mac addresses.  You can do this with scapy using arpcachepoison method or with a third party program like ettercap.

Once this is complete your method of using sniff() and send() should work a little bit better just make sure you change the packet before you get to the sending part ;) Here is a small example of how you could do that...here I just change the IP header destination address but you could change anything you want.

```
from scapy import *

def chgSend(x):
    x[IP].dst = '192.168.1.1'
    send(x)
while 1:
    sniff(prn=chgSend)
```

dc

Comment: I know this is slightly older thread but a similar one - Can one change the outgoing packet in a more complex way? Such as inserting another kind of http header in an http payload without modifying IP or TCP headers. Any reference to relevant api etc?

Comment: Absolutely, however, depending what you want to change it may involve other modules. For instance if you wanted to change the payload on all http GET request packets I would use re to parse the header and then send modified packet accordingly..

Comment: I actually want to insert a new http header. This would mean overwriting the last \r\n and adding a few more fields.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem,

I think the problem is that you have enabled ip_forward so the original packet is forwarded to the original destination before the modified packet is sent by scapy.

Theorically, the solution is to create a rule in iptables forwarding the packets what you want to modify to another port (This is more or less what Ettercap does internaly),

```
      i.e = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port "YourInterestingPort" -j REDIRECT   --to-port 1234
```

And then in scapy listen to that port, modify the packet and send the packet to the original port.

This solution is difficult to implement because of the filtering, you have to redirect and modify only the packets that you want and exclude syn ack arp etc...

If you want to modify the responses of a server, A more simple way to do it is, instead of modify the packets on the fly, to act like an intermediary.

- arpspoof
- iptables
- Open a socket, receive the packet, open a connection and send it to the original destination (pretending you were the client). Then, receive the answer from the original destination, modify the answer, and return it to the original querier.

  ```
  while True:
     c, addr = s_mb.accept()             # Establish connection with client.
     query = c.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     s.connect((IP, PORT))
     s.send(PACKET)
     response = s.recv(1024)
     if response = "THIS IS THE RESPONSE THAT I WANT TO MODIFY":
      if(real_simulation):
          fakeresponse = "MODIFIED RESPONSE"
          #print "The packet has beeb modified"
         else:
          fakeresponse = response
     s.close()     
     c.send(fakeresponse)
  ```

(Sorry for the dirty code)

Answer (score 0):

If you use scapy send() function then it will create a new packet but with MITMf you dont need any send function, just change packet fields like scapy syntax, without use send func or need to create new packet...

this is a good github repo for  [**MITMf**](https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/MITMf)
this repo is like scapy and written from scratch with compelete abilities for your target.
**sample code :**

```
if packet.haslayer(ICMP):
   log.info('Got an ICMP packet!')
   packet.dst = '192.168.1.0'
```